# Convert Belkin Wireless Ethernet Bridge to Access Point

Tags: firmware, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

I'm sure this is completely impossible but I thought I'd ask anyway.

I have a Belkin F5D7330 Wireless Ethernet Bridge.

Is there any hack / firmware or anything that would convert it into an Access Point rather than a bridge?

Surely the hardware inside must be pretty identical.

Comment: I'd rather trade it to AP, though the hardware is the same as for the 11g AP Belkin sells. This is rather a practical "gaming adapter", or "client device", which should be given a good home with someone who needs it. Funny, but these devices with client firmware are more expensive than APs, with same hardware.

Comment: Me slow - editing dropped. Just wanted to add: I've had this device and the AP sibling, and fortunately I got rid of the AP FW version. Not worth the 28 &euro; (£25).